# React Native - RecyclerViewBackedScrollView not updating

Tags: android, react-native, native

I am trying to use ListView with renderScrollComponent as RecyclerViewBackedScrollView it works only if data already exists which is not what i want as i fetch the data first then update the list datasource but the problem is it's not updating, It only updates if use renderScrollComponent as ScrollView or drop the renderScrollComponent all together.

**ListView**

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.documents}
    enableEmptySections={true}
    renderRow={(rowData) => this._renderRow(rowData)}
    renderScrollComponent={props => <RecyclerViewBackedScrollView {...props} />}
/>
```

**RenderRow**

```
_renderRow(rowData) {
    return <HighNormalLowDetailsRow key={rowData.id} navigator={this.props.navigator} rowData={rowData}
                                    fields={this.props.fields}/>
};
```

**Update State**

```
let responseJson = await response.json();

console.log('-- got data --');
this.setState({documents: this.state.documents.cloneWithRows(responseJson), animating: false});
```